# Windows 10 on a MacBookAir7,1 does not work with one particular Wi-Fi access point

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, boot-camp

There is a MacBook Air (supposedly `MacBookAir7,1`) with Windows 10 installed that stopped working with one particular access point after a vacation. Other devices work with the same access point well. This laptop works well with other access points. There are also no problems when macOS is booted.

The symptoms are really weird: DHCP works well, and so does ping to the router, to `8.8.8.8` and to `google.com` (so DNS seems to work, too), but HTTP(S) times out.

There's ESET Internet Security installed, which we have tried completely turning off, with no results. The symptoms persist in Safe Mode with Networking.

We have tried running the commands:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

from the administrative shell and rebooting, with no changes in the behaviour.

We have tried rolling back the drivers, which resulted in the machine not being able to connect at all, so we rolled back the rollback.

We have also tried downloading the Boot Camp drivers using [brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier), removing the old drivers and installing the Boot Camp drivers, which did not help, either.

What else can we do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: What 802.11 mode is the access point?  What 802.11 modes does your network device support?

Comment: `802.11n`, at least the AP description says it's "n-compatible".

Comment: Is it in mixed AES/TKIP security mode? Unless you have really old devices, keep it in AES/CCMP encryption modes.

Answer (score 0):

I would never have guessed it, but enabling the FIPS compatibility somehow got it working again: [image]